# Karate - Cucumber report - total feature time duration is wrong according to called features in it

Tags: automated-tests, karate

I use Karate with Cucumber reports.

I have noticed that when I insert some feature to another feature (using call function) feature execution time is doubled in report because there is one runtime for each step and also total time of inserted feature is displayed and it is added to the total time of the whole test.

Example:

```
-----Step----------------------------------------------------time(s)-----

* call read('classpath:ui/common/login.feature')..............9.402
ui/common/login.feature.......................................0.000
> * driver baseUrl............................................8.543
> Then waitFor('input[name=email]')...........................0.098
> * retry().input('input[name=email]', email).................0.293
> * retry().input('input[name=password]', password)...........0.154
> * retry().click('{span}Login')..............................0.052
```

I expect that this part of code has duration about 9s, but in report it is doubled due to called feature (9.402 + 8.543 + 0.098 +...). It do not correspond with reality.

Have you any idea how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: this is a bug, which I don't consider the highest priority. ideally submit a good example because it is not clear here what report is the problem, JUnit or Cucumber. And if you can contribute a fix, nothing like it ;) https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue